# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flareml_utils'

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to import libraries that are required for my class project, this is the code

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks')

#!pip install matplotlib==3.4.2 numpy==1.19.5 scikit-learn==0.24.2 sklearn-extensions==0.0.2 pandas==1.2.4
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
# Data manipulation
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Training the models
# The following libraries are used to train the algorithms: Random Forest, MLP, and ELM.
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

from sklearn_extensions.extreme_learning_machines.elm import GenELMClassifier # ERROR
from sklearn_extensions.extreme_learning_machines.random_layer import RBFRandomLayer, MLPRandomLayer # ERROR

# Visualizations
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from flareml_utils import plot_custom_result # ERROR
# Running the training, testing and prediction. 
from flareml_train import train_model # ERROR
from flareml_test import test_model # ERROR
```

---

but I keep on getting this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-fc8aafaf4a3d> in <module>
     23 # Visualizations
     24 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
---> 25 from flareml_utils import plot_custom_result # ERROR
     26 # Running the training, testing and prediction.
     27 from flareml_train import train_model # ERROR

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flareml_utils'
```

I ran the code on google colab and attempted using !pip install flareml_utils , it gave me this error
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flareml_utils (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for flareml_utils

I also tried !pip install flareml_utils and it produced this
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flareml_utils'ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flareml_utils'